# How do I properly clean up a UIButton

Tags: iphone, events, uibutton, touch

I am having issues with UIButton with the iPhone SDK.  I've determined that when I have a UIButton held down when the parent is removed (and the uibutton subsequently removed), I get some strange behavior.  In my case, the app stops receiving any input whatsoever, as if the cleaned up held-down button has hijacked the input system somehow.

Does anyone know if there is an appropriate way to clean up the UIButton that would release what I'm guessing is the framework thinking the released button is still held down?

Update: Adding detail to my issue
Basically, the simplified situation is that I have a root view with two characters (actors, not letter characters) and a number of buttons, among other views.  The user can use the buttons to affect direction of movement, and when the characters are close to each other, the scene moves forward immediately into another mode, i.e. the buttons slide off, the view cleans up, and I construct a new one.

What this necessitates is the ability to immediately move on and clean up even if the button is still held down.  I figured I could pull some tricks to delay cleaning the button up, but I would be surprised if there isn't simply some way to properly clean up the button for removal regardless of what state it is currently in.  Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem wasn't a button being held down but rather a call to set the center coordinate of a mapview with animation on, i.e.

[mMapView setCenterCoordinate:mCoordinates animated:YES];

If the view was cleaned up while the animation was still moving, the app would no longer respond to user input.  I'm not certain why this is the case, still, but setting the animated flag to NO ensured the problem didn't arise.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you would explain what behavior you are expecting. If you are calling *-removeFromSuperview* while holding down the view you want to remove (or its parent), I would suggest you instead hide the view and set some flag you can look for when the user finishes holding that will at that point call *-removeFromSuperview*.